# Programing acceleration in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to get my player to move based off acceleration and velocity. Here is how the velocity is found and the player is moved:

```
vel.x += acceleration.x;
coordinates.x += vel.x;
```

The `coordinates` controls where the player is. Here is how acceleration is calculated:

```
if(moveRight && !(acceleration.x >= .1f)){
    acceleration.x += .1f * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
}
```

**First question:** Is this a good way to move the player if I am going to use mass and force to move the player.

I am also trying to get the player to come to a halt based off the acceleration, here is the extended version of the above code where I try to do this:

```
if(moveRight && !(acceleration.x >= .1f)){
    acceleration.x += .1f * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
}else if(!moveRight && (vel.x > 0)){
    acceleration.x -= .1f * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
}
```

However, this doesn't work. When I move forward it accelerates forward, then when I let go, it stops, then shoots backwards.

**Second question:** How can I get the above code to work in the way I desired.

Thanks for any help regarding these few questions.

Comment: I'm just going to say this first: `!(acceleration.x >= .1f)` is a _lot less_ readable than simply `acceleration.x < .1f` IMHO. Second: can you be more specific than "doesn't work"? How does the output differ from what you expect?

Comment: @Arc676 I edited the question

Comment: What is `movementSpeed`?

Comment: Use a debugger. It is not surprising that `vel.x` would be negative and stay negative at some point with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [question about friction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667034/simple-physics-based-movement). By playing with the friction coefficient, you can get a pleasing gradual slow down in movement. It's worth asking if you are aware of existing physics engines for Java that might make this whole thing a lot simpler: [JBox2d](http://www.jbox2d.org/) is just for 2D, and [JBullet](http://jbullet.advel.cz/) is a port of the 3D Bullet engine.