# Simulink projectile motion with air resistance simulation

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

I want to do Simulink model of projectile motion with air resistance.
[image: I have already done this].

X0 is the initial speed of x and Y0 is the initial speed of y. So the initial speed is V0 = 8 m/s.

How do I considering the air resistance, weight, start height and the initial angel?
Drag coefficient C = 0.01

Comment: There are different ways to model drag. [This may be of interest to you.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/667034/52738)

Comment: But how I can do it with "Gain" block

Comment: You can find the equations of motion at http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ProjectileWithAirDrag/ (for example). Now it's up to you nto implement them in Simulink with basic blocks, it's not hard.