# What on earth is going in in my particle simulation?

Tags: python, numpy, physics

I've got my colliding balls simulation kind of working but the particles go crazy.

Some of them stick to each other and spin around. others kind of get stuck at the edges.

i can't think of why... could anyone help me out here? thanks

This code uses the Taichi Gui. I intend to use the taichi decorators in the future but for now I'm just testing it with regular python

```
import taichi as ti
import numpy as np

ti.init(arch=ti.vulkan)

gui = ti.GUI('Circles Test', res=(600, 600))

numpoints = 20
centres = np.random.random((numpoints, 2))
velocities = np.random.uniform(-1,1, (numpoints,2))
radius = 20
guiradius = 0.04
damping = 0.9
timestep = 1/60

'''
@ti.kernel
def randompoints():
    for i, j in centres:
        centres[i,j] =ti.random()
'''
#randompoints()
print(centres[1])

def wallcollision(centres, velocities):
    for i in range(len(centres)):
        if centres[i][0] - guiradius <=0:
            velocities[i][0] = -damping*velocities[i][0]
        if centres[i][0] + guiradius >=1:
            velocities[i][0] = -damping*velocities[i][0]
        
        if centres[i][1] - guiradius <=0:
            velocities[i][1] = -damping*velocities[i][1]
        if centres[i][1] + guiradius >=1:
            velocities[i][1] = -damping*velocities[i][1]
    return velocities

def selfcollision(centres, velocities):
    for i in range(len(centres)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(centres)):
            if np.linalg.norm(centres[i]-centres[j]) < 2*guiradius:
                print("Collision!")
                vitemp = np.copy(velocities[i])
                vitemp = velocities[i] - (np.dot(velocities[i]-velocities[j], centres[i]-centres[j])*(centres[i]-centres[j])/(np.linalg.norm(centres[i]-centres[j])**2))
                velocities[j] = velocities[j] - (np.dot(velocities[j]-velocities[i], centres[j]-centres[i])*(centres[j]-centres[i])/(np.linalg.norm(centres[j]-centres[i])**2))
                velocities[i] = vitemp
                
                ##velocities[i] = -velocities[i]
    return velocities

def update(centres, velocities):
    centres += velocities*timestep
    velocities = wallcollision(centres, velocities)
    velocities = selfcollision(centres, velocities)

while gui.running:
    gui.circles(centres, radius, color=0xEEEEF0)
    gui.show()
    update(centres, velocities)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel While I mostly agree with the first part, the OP *did actually provided* a minimal reproducible example! It is *fully reproducible* so I easily did it. The OP can hardly make it smaller since the (same) bug is located simultaneously in `wallcollision` and `selfcollision`. How would you have made it more specific while being still reproducible? Most of the questions asked by other newcomers often don't even provide an MRE like this one (and when they do, they don't get so many downvotes like here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when a collision is detected, the velocity is modified but not the centre, and **the velocity is not always big enough for particles to escape the collision area in the next frame**. This means particles can stay in collision during many frames. This causes the velocity components to oscillate between negative and positive values making the collision escape sometimes impossible. This is why particles are somehow glued together. The same issue happens on the wall : when the centre of a particle is beyond the walls, the velocity components can oscillate so the particle is glued to the walls. This kind of issue arises quite frequently in basic physics simulations. A simple fix is simply to **correct the centres** so for the particles not to collide in the next frames.

Here is the corrected code:

```py
# My parameters:
# guiradius = 0.04
# radius = 600*guiradius # More accurate visually

def wallcollision(centres, velocities):
    for i in range(len(centres)):
        if centres[i][0] - guiradius <=0:
            velocities[i][0] = -damping*velocities[i][0]
            centres[i][0] = guiradius
        if centres[i][0] + guiradius >=1:
            velocities[i][0] = -damping*velocities[i][0]
            centres[i][0] = 1 - guiradius
        if centres[i][1] - guiradius <=0:
            velocities[i][1] = -damping*velocities[i][1]
            centres[i][1] = guiradius
        if centres[i][1] + guiradius >=1:
            velocities[i][1] = -damping*velocities[i][1]
            centres[i][1] = 1 - guiradius
    return velocities

def selfcollision(centres, velocities):
    for i in range(len(centres)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(centres)):
            distance = np.linalg.norm(centres[i]-centres[j])
            if distance < guiradius * 2:
                print("Collision!")
                vitemp = np.copy(velocities[i])
                vitemp = velocities[i] - (np.dot(velocities[i]-velocities[j], centres[i]-centres[j])*(centres[i]-centres[j])/distance**2)
                velocities[j] = velocities[j] - (np.dot(velocities[j]-velocities[i], centres[j]-centres[i])*(centres[j]-centres[i])/distance**2)
                velocities[i] = vitemp

                # Fix the centers
                overlapping_distance = guiradius * 2 - distance
                direction = (centres[j] - centres[i]) / distance
                epsilon = 1e-6 # Additional safe gap to avoid particles to collide again
                shift = overlapping_distance * direction * (0.5 + epsilon)
                centres[i] -= shift
                centres[j] += shift
    return velocities
```

Please note that in more realistic simulations, the force is dependent of the collision surface (using a non-trivial formula if one want to simulate electrons responsible for the ball repulsion) so the collisions should not occur for a long time.

Comment: Thank you! This is great. I'd missed the.... points
Perhaps I should have referred to this as a billiard simulation or just balls colliding.

Comment: Should I have posted this in a different forum? I thought it was a bug in my code rather than a logic/concept error on my part. Thanks again i realise I missed out a big part of simulation logic-  updating positions during collisions.

Comment: @ollied I think stack-overflow is the best forum of all stack-exchange ones for this question quite suited. This is not rare for programming problem to be solved using not just programming fix on SO.

Comment: @ollied For example, there are many good questions of people seeing numerical instability issues in their code that can be solved with math-related trick. Such questions often do not fit on mathoverflow because issues are due to the discretisation of numbers. In fact, this is a field of computed science research. But many programmers often consider that as pure math issues (unfortunately). This does not fit well on cs.stackexchange nor mathoverflow, and while scicomp.stackexchange might, AFAIK it is still quite new/experimental.

Comment: @ollied A more concrete example of such question can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667034/simple-physics-based-movement) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling) (the later might interest you). These questions are clearly not just programming ones but they have been well received by the community.

Comment: @ollied Tags play an important role on whether a question is well received. People looking the "python"/"numpy" tags often expect fully programming question, while the one looking "physics" one do not. The former group can downvote questions because of that.

Comment: @ollied Note that, theoretically, your comment and mine are not well-suited here but on https://meta.stackexchange.com ;) .